# NullPointerException ao chamar método de serviço na classe de teste

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito

Estou tentando *mockar* o método `listarHistorico` da classe de repositório `historicoRepository` mas da **null pointer** quando chamo o método real `listarHistoricoAcessos()` da classe de serviço que é o método que quero testar.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class HistoricoAcessosServiceTest {
    
    /*
     * @Autowired private MockMvc mockMvc;
     */
    
    
    @InjectMocks
    private HistoricoAcessosService historicoService;
    
    @Mock
    private HistoricoAcessosRepositoryCriteria historicoRepository;

    Page<UsuariosAcessos> usuariosAcessosPaginados;

    Page<HistoricoAcessosDTO> dtosPaginados;
    
    List<HistoricoAcessosDTO> dtos = new ArrayList<>();
    
    List<UsuariosAcessos> usuariosAcessos = new ArrayList<>();
    
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 10);
    
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
       
        dtos.add(new HistoricoAcessosDTO(new Date(), "Demetrius", false,false,false,true,false));
        usuariosAcessos.add(new UsuariosAcessos(1L, new Date()));
        dtosPaginados = new PageImpl<>(dtos, pageable, 10);
        usuariosAcessosPaginados = new PageImpl<>(usuariosAcessos, pageable, 10);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void validate_busca_success() throws ParseException, ParametroInvalidoException {

        Page<UsuariosAcessos> mockProductPage = new PageImpl<>(usuariosAcessos);
        Page<HistoricoAcessosDTO> mockDtos = new PageImpl<>(dtos);
        //HistoricoAcessosService mockService = mock(HistoricoAcessosService.class);
        
        
        when(historicoRepository.listarHistorico(any(Pageable.class), eq(null), eq(null), eq(null), eq("Demetrius")))
            .thenReturn(mockProductPage);
        
         
         Page<HistoricoAcessosDTO> dtosBusca = historicoService.listarHistoricoAcessos(pageable, null, null, null, "demetrius");
         
         //assertNotNull(dtosBusca);
         
    }

}
```

método da classe de serviço

```
@Service
public class HistoricoAcessosService {

    @Autowired
    private HistoricoAcessosRepositoryCriteria historicoRepository;
    
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date dataInicioConvertida = null;
    Date dataFimConvertida = null;


    public Page<HistoricoAcessosDTO> listarHistoricoAcessos(Pageable pageable, String intervalo, String dataInicio, String dataFim, String usuario) 
            throws ParseException, ParametroInvalidoException {
        
        dataInicioConvertida = null;
        dataFimConvertida = null;

        if (StringUtils.hasText(dataInicio) && StringUtils.hasText(dataFim)) {          
            try {
                dataInicioConvertida = format.parse(dataInicio);
                dataFimConvertida = format.parse(dataFim);  
            } catch(ParseException e) {
                throw new ParametroInvalidoException(DATA_INVALIDA.getMessage());
            }
            
            if(dataInicioConvertida.after(dataFimConvertida)) {
                 throw new ParametroInvalidoException(DATA_INICIO_MAIOR_QUE_DATA_FIM.getMessage());
            }
        }   
        
        Page<UsuariosAcessos> historico = historicoRepository.listarHistorico(pageable, intervalo, dataInicioConvertida, dataFimConvertida, usuario);
        List<HistoricoAcessosDTO> dtos = new ArrayList<>();

        for (UsuariosAcessos usuarioAcesso : historico) {
            dtos.add(new HistoricoAcessosDTO(usuarioAcesso));
        }
        
        Page<HistoricoAcessosDTO> dtosPaginados = new PageImpl<>(dtos, pageable, historico.getTotalElements());
        
        return dtosPaginados;
    }

}
```

erro que dá

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.data.domain.Page.iterator()" because "historico" is null
    at HistoricoAcessosService.listarHistoricoAcessos(HistoricoAcessosService.java:73)
```

Comment: Aparentemente o `historicoRepository.listarHistorico` está retornando `null` por alguma razão...

Comment: Essa chamada `historicoRepository.listarHistorico(pageable, intervalo, dataInicioConvertida, dataFimConvertida, usuario);` retorna `null`, voce fez o mock correto da classe de repositorio? Talvez o erro por causa de `eq("Demetrius")`, com "D" maiúsculo?....